# jQuery UI Tabs loading ASPX file - After the ASP button is pressed - displays "resource cannot be found."

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am new to both jQuery/AJAX and have a problem where I'm using the jQuery ui tabs. Basically in each tab I load their separate .aspx pages and attempt to do the regular processing work. (It loads correctly) My problem is that I have a button on that loaded tab and whenever the button is click, it attempts to process the request (I want to process the tab without reloading the entire page) - but the first issue right now is that I am getting an error saying..."Server Error in '/' Application. (The .aspx pages is in their own file directory - and that may be the error?) Below is the code I'm currently using. Any help or ideas would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/MemberPages/tab1/tab1.aspx">TAB1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/MemberPages/tab2/tab2.aspx">TAB2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/MemberPages/tab3/tab3.aspx">TAB3</a></li>
        <li><a href="/MemberPages/tab4/tab4.aspx">TAB4</a></li>
        <li><a href="/MemberPages/tab5/tab5.aspx">TAB5</a></li>
        <li><a href="/MemberPages/tab6/tab6.aspx">TAB6</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
                ui.jqXHR.error(function () {
                    ui.panel.html(
        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
        "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

------Purchasing aspx back-end

```
Protected Sub tp_btn_Process_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles tp_btn_Process.Click

'database code for insertion

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not load an aspx page via ajax, and wait the functions and the JavaScript and the buttons to work as if you run it alone.

Why ? because you have a basic page with a form tag, and inside that you fully load one more different page with a new form - and the full struct is now a mess, you have two viewstates, one post form inside the other and other stuff like that.

Now if you make any post back, the post back data is a mess and the code behind will not accept it.

An alternative if you still like to load the full page in a tab, is to use iframes and not ajax. Iframe is like a full page inside a page, with out mixing the one post with the other.

Similar: [how to use iframe instead of div with jquery ui tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042065/how-to-use-iframe-instead-of-div-with-jquery-ui-tabs)

Comment: Awesome! I've adjusted based on what you stated - but I have another question now, is it possible to use jQuery/AJAX or some other trickery to only load the tabs whenever it's pressed? Thanks!

Comment: @jsit208 I do not understand what you ask for. Can you please explain more ?

Comment: @jsit208 If you use ajax to load some information's, then do not use a fully page, but an ashx handler, or if its a page avoid the headers, body, form tags.

Comment: Actually I resolved the issue. The issue pertained to loading the iframes only when the tab button was clicked.   ["jQuery and iFrames"](http://dean.resplace.net/blog/2011/08/jquery-tabs-iframes/) was an excellent reference that helped me!